# I have an 3D array of size (144, 173, 360). Is there is taking the average of only every 12th index?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, jupyter, slice

I have a 3D array that is shape: 144,173, 360. I want to take the mean of the first axis (size 144) but only take the mean of every 12th element, so taking the mean of only:

```
0th, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11th index of first axis
```

then taking the average of:

```
12th, 13, 14, ... 23rd indices of the first axis, etc.
```

I tried this by making a for loop to include only every 12th index using ::, but am I looping over the correct range? The output array's shape is the same as the original array... so makes me think I am not looping over the right range?

```
array = np.random.rand(144,173,360)

# trying to take mean of every 12th index of first axis

array_mean_every_12th_index = []

for i in range(12):
    array_mean_every_12th_index.append(np.mean(array[i::12],axis=0))
array_mean_every_12th_index = np.array(array_mean_every_12th_index)
```

what might be wrong with my for loop? and how would I take the mean of only every 12th index of the first axis (axis = 0, size 144)?

Comment: this takes the mean of the 12 flattened arrays for index on axis 0 of 0...11, 12...23 etc `np.array([x.mean() for x in np.split(array,12)])`. Not sure if this is it what you want.

Comment: it's not completely clear to me what you want: `i::12` takes every 12th index but in the beginning you want to take the mean of 0th to 11th, then 12th to 23rd etc index.

Comment: I think my way is better.

Comment: hm yes! your way works as well thanks! I have had some problems with np.reshape in the past though...sometimes it not outputting the original values which is why I am sometimes hesitant to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method is probably to reshape your array:

```
array_mean_every_12th_index = array.reshape(-1, 12, *array.shape[1:]).mean(axis=1)
```

When you reshape an axis like that into two axes, it allows you to sum up either every 12th element (`mean(axis=0)`), or every batch of 12 (`mean(axis=1)`). You seem to want the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Fix to the problem:

```
array = np.random.rand(144,173,360)

# trying to take mean of every 12th index of first axis

array_mean_every_12th_index = []

for i in range(12):
    array_mean_every_12th_index.append(np.mean(array[(12*i):(12*(i+1))],axis=0))
array_mean_every_12th_index = np.array(array_mean_every_12th_index)
```